# Fetch Twitter usernames from ACAccountstore -

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, acaccountstore

I am taking ACAccount store in an array as -

```
 NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
```

By printing arrayOfAccounts -

```
  (
  "type:com.apple.twitter\nidentifier: 9E8DD039-D210-49EB-90D3-797017EC9F37\naccountDescription: @kaleshnewage\nusername: kaleshnewage\nobjectID: x-coredata://8CD38D83-7C1C-4542-BE4B-7007B6586675/Account/p24\nenabledDataclasses: {(\n)}\nenableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(\n)}\nproperties: {\n    \"user_id\" = 1407688573;\n}\nparentAccount: (null)\nowningBundleID:(null)",
"type:com.apple.twitter\nidentifier: 888F056F-8BB2-4847-91D3-CFFE93770F01\naccountDescription: @dasarun5\nusername: dasarun5\nobjectID: x-coredata://8CD38D83-7C1C-4542-BE4B-7007B6586675/Account/p25\nenabledDataclasses: {(\n)}\nenableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(\n)}\nproperties: {\n    \"user_id\" = 120014192;\n}\nparentAccount: (null)\nowningBundleID:(null)",
"type:com.apple.twitter\nidentifier: 3BB57617-0436-4801-B302-CE7C67D2E2A5\naccountDescription: @arunjoseph700\nusername: arunjoseph700\nobjectID: x-coredata://8CD38D83-7C1C-4542-BE4B-7007B6586675/Account/p28\nenabledDataclasses: {(\n)}\nenableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(\n)}\nproperties: {\n    \"user_id\" = 1068508537;\n}\nparentAccount: (null)\nowningBundleID:(null)"
)
```

Now I want to take only the usernames into another array, How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accountsWithAccountType:` returns an array of `ACAccount` therefore you can do something like this:

```
for (ACAccount *account in arrayOfAccounts) {
    NSLog(@"Username: %@", account.username);
}
```